# ImportError for any rosdep command

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any `rosdep` command I try to run gives me the same error:

```
[robosalmon ~/catkin_ws_source_pkgs (localhost)]$ rosdep -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
    from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .lookup import RosdepDefinition, RosdepView, RosdepLookup, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .sources_list import SourcesListLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .gbpdistro_support import get_gbprepo_as_rosdep_data, download_gbpdistro_as_rosdep_data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .platforms.debian import APT_INSTALLER
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py", line 34, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import OS_DEBIAN, OS_LINARO, OS_UBUNTU, OsDetect
ImportError: cannot import name OS_LINARO
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install python-rosdep` and it was apparently successful, but didn't fix `rosdep`.

How can I fix rosdep?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206533/importerror-for-any-rosdep-command/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured this out. The solution was to pip install it.

```
$ sudo pip install rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) with karma: 233 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-02**:
This shouldn't be necessary. Which platform are you on?

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-04-06**:
result of `$ uname -a`: `Linux robosalmon 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:01:04 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Comment by [Jackson Carter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20733/jackson-carter/) on 2015-10-02**:
I had the same problem when running "sudo rosdep init" and this solution appeared to fix it. On my system: $uname -a: Linux my-name 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I recently upgraded the computer from Precise to Trusty.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-10-04**:
I suspect you have an out-of-date version of rospkg. Try upgrading rospkg with `sudo apt-get install python-rospkg` instead of installing rosdep through pip.